# Spring JAVA SSL - No name matching localhost found

Tags: spring, ssl, certificate, keystore

I have two SSL end-points that share the same application.properties and key store file.

I want to have one end-point call the other, but getting an error `No name matching localhost found`

How can I adjust this to allow one microservice to call the other(s) as intended below?

I have played with the following to attempt a solution to no avail:

- [javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier()](https://mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/java-security-cert-certificateexception-no-name-matching-localhost-found/)
- Created a localhost certificate and added it to the keystore

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
public class submitapplicationcontroller {

    @Bean
    public WebClient.Builder getWebClientBuilder(){
        return WebClient.builder();
    }

    @Autowired private WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder;

    @PostMapping("/submitapplication")
    public String submitapplication() {
        
        /***   Returns Error Found Below   ***/

        String response = webClientBuilder.build()
            .post()
            .uri("https://localhost:8080/validateaddress")
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class)
            .block();
        
        return response;
    }
}
```

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No name matching localhost found
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
|_ checkpoint ⇢ Request to POST https://localhost:8080/v1/validateaddress
```

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
public class validateaddresscontroller {
    
    @PostMapping("/validateaddress")
    public String validateaddress() {
        
        return "response";

    }

}
```

```
server.ssl.key-alias=server
server.ssl.key-password=asensitivesecret
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:server.jks
server.ssl.key-store-provider=SUN
server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
server.ssl.key-store-password=asensitivesecret
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was the way I went about creating and implementing the certificates. I had 2 separate keystores and certificates; one named "server", and one named "localhost". I added the localhost certificate to the server keystore, and applied the server keystore and certificate to the springboot application / application.properties.

What you have to do is create just one certificate and keystore dubbed "localhost" and you have to use that to apply to the application / application.properties.

What you should have after creating the localhost JKS and certificate

```
server.ssl.key-alias=localhost
server.ssl.key-password=asensitivesecret
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:localhost.jks
server.ssl.key-store-provider=SUN
server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
server.ssl.key-store-password=asensitivesecret
```

- Note: I don't believe you actually have to create a JKS named "localhost", just the certificate. I just did for testing purposes.